# DocumentFragment elements not visible for WebDriver

Tags: dom, selenium-webdriver

I have page to test

```
<div class="activity-container">
<!--fragment#54705578f9#head-->
<div fragment="54705578f9" class="activity-action">
    <span class="icon-arrow_drop_down"></span>
    <span class="actions-description">
        <b>Login</b>
    </span>
    <span>Date: 28/02/2019</span>
    <span>Time: 12:20</span></div>
<div class="activity-description" fragment="54705578f9" style="display: none;">
    <span></span>
    <span class="actions-no-info">No additional information</span>
</div>
<!--fragment#54705578f9#tail-->
<!--fragment#26552421c5#head--></div>
```

When i try to click on `//*[@class="activity-action"][1]` with webdriver i get 'Element not visible exception'.
Next step, check why element not visible for selenium:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('activity-action')[0].getBoundingClientRect()
```

response: 
`DOMRect {x: 359.3125, y: 343, width: 900, height: 59, top: 343, …}`

Element visible, now check parent:

`document.getElementsByClassName('activity-action')[0].parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()` and get `DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …}`

Parent element not visible so child is not visible too. But parent element is something weird:

`document.getElementsByClassName('activity-action')[0].parentNode`

returns: `<div fragment="54705578f9"></div>` and i dont understand how it could be. I cant see this element in chrome inspector. What is this?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('activity-action')[0].parentNode.parentNode
```

returns `<div class="activity-container">...</div>` this element must be returned in previous step.

Could i make element `//*[@class="activity-action"][1]` visible by modify it with JavascriptExecutor?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @frameq theoretically you can modify with JSExecutor but dont do it. Please provide full exception. Please also try adding wait for elementToBeClickable before your click

Comment: I want to understand why element `//*[@class="activity-action"][1]` has parent `<div fragment="54705578f9"></div>` and how can i edit DOMRect of this element.

Comment: I use  selenium server and got verbose output: `Completed command waitForElementVisible (15235 ms)` and  `Timed out while waiting for element <//div[@class="activity-container"]/div[1]> to be visible for 15000 milliseconds. - Expected "visible" but got: "not visible"`. Maybe i need to make bug in selenium bug tracker?

Comment: It sounds like that portion of the HTML is not visible and never will be. Is the info you need not in the visible portion of the page elsewhere? You can use JSE to get elements off the page even when they aren't visible but you should be selective when doing this because it's no longer a user scenario. Users can't access elements on the page that aren't visible.

Comment: I've got the same behaviour on a VueJS app with fragments. Look totally fine in chrome dev tools, but Selenium just doesn't think they are visible. Replicate the same HTML without fragments and all works. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

based on provided Exception:

> Completed command waitForElementVisible (15235 ms) and Timed out while waiting for element `<//div[@class="activity-container"]/div[1]>` to be visible for 15000 milliseconds. - Expected "visible" but got: "not visible

your xpath given to Selenium is wrong. Selenium try click **child** div of *activity-container* div which is *activity-description* div having `style="display: none;`

Please verify your xpath, for example in Chrome dev tools before passing it to Selenium test